# Big raster (DEM) loading too long in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem

I have a big geotiff file (resolution 2m, 192500 columns, 120000 rows, 100GB) representing a DEM model for a whole country. When I open in in ArcGIS it works fine, but in QGIS I need to wait half an hour for the file to load and show me the result. This make it impossible to perform any operations on the raster.

What can I do to make it work in QGIS? Why does this problem occur?

Edit: adding raster Info

[image]

Comment: Please show gdalinfo report of the DEM file. Important part is if GeoTIFF is written as tiled and if it has overviews.

Comment: no problem, but how and from where can I get it?

Comment: Through command line http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html or from menu Raster-Miscellaneous-Information.

Answer (score 3):

Your image has no overviews/pyramids. You can use GDAL to generate them:

```
gdaladdo -ro --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW DEFLATE --config PREDICTOR_OVERVIEW 2 swissALTI3D_LV03LN021.tif 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256
```

Comment: Probably ought to note that this will increase storage ~33%

Comment: As the original is not compressed, the overviews will probably be really really tiny.

Comment: I read about the pyramids but the problem is that the file is already big and there is a problem with finding a place to store it. Would it help somehow to compress it?

Comment: You can try `gdal_translate -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2 -co TILED=YES swissALTI3D_LV03LN021.tif swissALTI3D_LV03LN021_deflate.tif` which will easily reduce to the size by 10.